# For Loop in JavaScript is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, iteration

```js
const box = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
console.log(box.length);

const direction = [
  "top-start",
  "bottom-start",
  "left-start",
  "right-start",
  "top-center",
  "bottom-center",
  "left-center",
  "right-center",
  "top-end",
  "bottom-end",
  "left-end",
  "right-end"
];

box.forEach((el, index) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < direction.length; i++) {
    CreateTooltip(el, direction[index], "Hello, World!");
  }
});
```

The above mentioned code rendering `144` tooltips in `DOM` and I want only 12 with each should have different directions. I don't why this loop is not working! I tried to add `forEach` loop inside `for` loop but still the problem is same.

**NOTE** As some of you asked I pasted my entire code. Hope it will help you and then you will help me.

Comment: Well, you're creating and appending a new DIV element for each call, what did you expect to get? it will be 144 since you have 12 `.box` elements and 12 directions.

Comment: @Pezhvak how can I solve this problem?? I am not a pro in JavaScript!

Comment: `box.forEach((element, index) => {  
        CreateTooltip(element, direction[index], 'Hello, World!');
}) ` use this code for creating tooltip

Comment: @Flames Thank You So Much!! it worked. If you want tooltips for any project remember me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in the index of each element like this and get the corresponding value from the direction array

```
box.forEach((element, index) => {  
        CreateTooltip(element, direction[index], 'Hello, World!');
})
```

Comment: Your code partially worked but I am still getting 144 element rendered in ```DOM```! and I want only 12.

Comment: I think the problem might be with the CreateTooltip function, could you share the code for it?

Comment: This looks like a perfectly valid solution assuming the length of `box` is equal to the length of `direction`.  Seems like the bug might be in your `CreateTooltip` function.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working well, as you are iterating over list of boxes and inside that you have another iteration, so the result of your code will always be (number of boxes)*(number of directions) = 144..

So you can Iterate only on boxes or on direction by manipulating one and other lists by there index numbers as given below..

```
    $(box).each(function(i,v){console.log(direction[i])})
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't use jQuery. Really appreciate though. 

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Queryselectorall**  , if it is class use dot , or if you are using id use #

```
const box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
```

Comment: it is not about naming error I am having problem in rendering!

Answer (score 0):

From what you have stated, namely wanting 12 tooltips (same as `direction` index counts) but getting 144 tooltips (144/12 = 12) you should have 12 elements with `.box` class in your page. the problem is in your query selection.

```
const box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
console.log(box.length); // this should show 12
```

what you need to do is to set an ID for your element or create a loop for the box (array at this point) and execute your `CreateTooltip` logic for each of them separately.

**Note:** I suggest you to test your `CreateTooltip` in a testing environment (separated file created to test your code) with only one `.box` element, it's possible that the library you're using does not support multiple calls of `CreateTooltip` for a single element, that might be the reason you're getting 144 elements instead of 12.

Comment: I think I should mention my entire code! Let me do it real quick. Then please tell me what is the actual problem!!